# How to make {{#each}} stop iterate at a certain condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, iteration, handlebars.js

So im trying to make a little quiz and i want every question with his choices to be display, and when the user clicks the next button, the current question is deleted and the next one with the choices is beign showen.
something like that:

question: what?
choices: 1-a,2-b,3-c,4-d

"next" button.

and by clicking next the current question is deleted(also the choices)
and the next question appears:
question: why?
choices: 1-z,2-x,3-y,4-r

"next" button

here is my html code:

```
<div class="well span6 offset3">
            <script id="try" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                <form>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Login</legend>
                        <input id="fn" type="text" name="userF" class="input-block-level" placeholder="First Name">
                        <input id="ln" type="text" name="userL" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Last Name">
                        <input id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="login">
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
                {{#each this}}
                <div><h4>{{question}}</h4></div>
                <ul>
                {{#each choices}}
                <li><input type="radio" name="{{../question}}" value="{{this}}">{{this}}</li>
                {{/each}}
                </ul>
                {{/each}}
                <input type="submit" id="next" class="btn btn-primary" value="Next" placeholder="Next">
            </script>
```

here is my array:

```
var allQuestions = [
    new QuestionCreate("Which is the Capital of Australia?", ["Syndey", "Canberra", "Melbourne", "Hobart"], 2),
    new QuestionCreate("How much population there is in Australia?", ["22M", "18m", "20M", "23M"], 4),
    new QuestionCreate("How is the most expensive soccer player ever?", ["Cristiano Ronaldo", "Messi", "Zlatan Ibrahimovic", "Luis Figo"], 1),
    new QuestionCreate("Which national team as the most wins in the Fifa World Cup?", ["Italy", "Spain", "Brazil", "England"], 3)
];
```

and here is my compile:
    theTemplateScript = $("#try").html();

```
var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);

$(".offset3").append(theTemplate(allQuestions));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can do something like this after rendering the first question:

```
var counter = 0 
$("#next").click(function() {
  $(".offset3").html("")
  counter = counter + 1 
  $(".offset3").append(theTemplate(allQuestions[counter]));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

worked it around with event delegation:

```
theTemplateScript = $("#try").html();

var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);

var counter = 0

$(".offset3").append(theTemplate(allQuestions[counter]));

$("div").on("click","#next", function() {
    $(".offset3").html("")
    counter = counter + 1
    $(".offset3").append(theTemplate(allQuestions[counter]));
    return counter;
});
```